# Log HTTP requests from non-browser app

Tags: proxy, httpwebrequest

I would like to log http webrequests coming from an external source to a custom piece of software on my desktop (windows xp).  there is no way to configure a proxy on this custom application, that I know of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as a [reverse proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp).  That will allow you to inspect incoming requests.